# Can MySQL be set up locally on a development computer?

Tags: mysql

Is there any local MySQL database which I can create on my system, just like the localhost we run on our system.

I never thought of this situation since we have our beta servers and live servers with database already set up in our offices.

I am creating an app on my own, that's why I need to setup a local db of mine.

Comment: You are creating a _web app_, or some kind of mobile app needing its own embedded database?

Comment: You do realize you can install mysql locally right? http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

Comment: "localhost" is a hostname that your computer (any computer) uses to refer to itself. And yes, MySQL can be installed locally, and accessed on the local adapter.

Comment: @micheal thanks for the help.. I need to create a web app

Comment: @bryan i didnt know abt it.. I m feeling a bit dumb now :P.. Thnx :)

Comment: @BryanMoyles Which one should I download from the site? ..There are too many options Cluster,etc.

Comment: You might want to follow the LAMP/WAMP approach mentioned below if you're new to this. Otherwise, you can download the community edition

Answer (score 1):

You can use WAMP (or LAMP on linux) which is an integrated web development environment giving you access to your own LOCAL SQL databases accessible through your own machine's localhost. You will have full control to be able to create tables and administrate it.  I am currently doing that myself

[WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)